# Ajax request to RestControler Spring returned 403 error

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-rest

I try do ajax request with saving changes of the user my app.

I have written so ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/admin/users/" + cell.getRow().getData().id,
                type: "PUT",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(cell.getRow().getData())
            });
```

And I have written RestController:

```
@RestController
public class AdminRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @GetMapping("/admin/users")
    public List<UserAdminForm> findAllUsers(){

        return userMapper.toUserAdminFormList(userService.findAll());
    }

    @PutMapping("/admin/users/{id}")
    public void saveUser(@RequestBody UserAdminForm userAdminForm, @PathVariable Long id) {

        userService.saveUser(userAdminForm, id);

    }

}
```

I tried to write PUT and POST.

I get next error:
[image]

Comment: show your pom.xml.your project may intergrate a security framwork.

Answer (score 0):

As [HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-66) states:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
> public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
> reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to
> make this information available to the client, the status code 404
> (Not Found) can be used instead.

Basically the resource you are trying to reach is forbiden.

I suspect your system has some authentication requirements you are not meeting. Check how you pass your credentials (headers), or maybe a token is being handled or some form of permission system.